# import tensorflow as tf: error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Help appreciated on following tensorflow installation issue, System: Windows 10 Home 64-bit

-Clean Installed Python 3.6.5 as Administrator

-Ran pip install tensorflow from Python's Script Directory via cmd-line (As administrator) (no errors)

Trying to execute following code (importing module):

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

gives following stack trace

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 658, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 571, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 922, in
>   create_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 658, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 571, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 922, in
>   create_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Help appreciated! :)

Comment: did you install the gpu version? have you tried updating it?

Comment: Have you used pip3 to install it or pip as you say in the description? For Python 3.x you need pip3.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan: I retried it, wiping python off my machine, reinstalling it, and then running pip3 install tensorflow. Same issue as above though Mntfr: As far as I am aware, pip3 install tensorflow installs the non-gpu version. If I wanted to install the gpu-version, i would run pip3 install tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 0):

These might be possible scenarios:

1. You need to install the MSVC 2019 redistributable
2. Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
3. Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
4. There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded